# Versions spring boot, spring cloud, ribbon not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, ribbon

I am learning how to work with microservices using spring boot and spring cloud. I am having problems choosing the spring cloud and boot versions - I can't use the `@RibbonClient` annotation because I have not found the dependency.

I want to use the latest versions of spring cloud and spring boot, but I'm not finding the ribbon dependency. I want to use **spring boot 2.4.1** and **spring cloud 2.20.0.x**.

Comment: Ribbon is no longer part of spring cloud 2020.0

Comment: Then currently ribbon is deprecated? if i want to learn microservices what, do i need to learn? i am new in this theme

Comment: Ribbon has been deprecated for more than a year. Spring Cloud Load balancer is our replacement

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Spring Cloud Netflix Ribbon has been deprecated and is not included in the `2020.0.0` release train. Spring Cloud LoadBalancer is the suggested alternative. You can read its docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-loadbalancer). You can follow a simple guide [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-cloud-loadbalancer/) and see a more robust sample [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-intro-demo).